# Can't load the assembly Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding in a C # 2010 project

Tags: c#, exception, qr-code, crystal-reports-2010

I'm a amateur programer and recently find myself doing a proyect for school.
In this program I use a mysql database,  dll for making dinamic QR codes and in other part of the same program, crystal reports, well, everything it's ok at this point.
The application works perfectly when I exectute it, using (F5) and does all I want, just like I want.
The problem comes out when I try to execute the .exe file, it comes out a warning when I access to the part that uses the QR generator. The exception says:

"No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Version=0.4.0.0 Culture = Neutral, PublicKey Token = e8a75d24b142be49' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado."

(Translated)

"Could not load file or assembly 'Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Version = 0.4.0.0 Culture = neutral, PublicKey Token = e8a75d24b142be49' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified."

I read about modifying the app.config file to make this error/exception  dissapear, i already do that and the error persist. And in the part of the Crystal Report, shows me a windows screen telling me "the aplication stop of working..."
Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?

Comment: Do you really have this assembly anywhere in your system?

Comment: I got the dll in the main folder, added by the wizard of c# to references in the proyect. I don't know if this is what you mean. Like I said, im noob at this, and thank you for answering